# Inserting elements into a list while iterating

Tags: python-2.7

I know this question has been asked many, many times. I understand why modifying a list that I am iterating over will not work. I came up with an idea, but I'd like feedback on if it might ever break, and what a better, perhaps more Pythonic way to do it might be. I want to take a string and insert the word 'like' every 3 words.

```
def hedge(string):
a = string.split()
keep_up = 0                       # To 'keep up' with the changing length of a
for i in range(3, len(a), 3):
a.insert(i+keep_up, 'like')
    keep_up += 1                  # Add 1 to keep_up every time 'like' is added, because this 
return ' '.join(a)                # messes with the index
```

This returns a string like:

his palms are like sweaty, knees weak, like arms are heavy. like there's vomit on like his sweater already, like mom's spaghetti.

Creating a new variable seems like it might not be the simplest way to go. Is there a better way?

Note: Before arriving at this solution, I tried iterating over a copy of 'a' several different ways, but since the length of 'a' is still changing, I didn't see how that would help.

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and `yield`, your code can be change as follow:

```
def hedge(s):
    for i, word in enumerate(s.split()):
        if i > 0 and i % 3 == 0:
            yield 'like'
        yield word

sentence1 = "his palms are sweaty, knees weak, arms are heavy. there's vomit on his sweater already, mom's spaghetti."
sentence2 = "his palms are like sweaty, knees weak, like arms are heavy. like there's vomit on like his sweater already, like mom's spaghetti."
assert ' '.join(hedge(sentence1)) == sentence2
```